# node.js and npm installation not working in windows

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

> ```
> fork/exec C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\nvm\elevate.cmd: The parameter is incorrect.:
> ```

This error is coming when I use the command `nvm use 11.0.0` on cmd.

Comment: you can install nodejs by nodejs main site https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: refer this for step by step installation https://www.guru99.com/download-install-node-js.html